# Debug django tests

Tags: django, django-tests

I see that  [TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) has a method [Debug()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.debug), but I can't find any example on how to implement it. As far as I've tried, nothing works.

Can anyone provide some code as to how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### debugunit.py

```
from unittest import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        print 'before'
        self.assertEquals(2+2, 5)
        print 'after'
```

### run

> python -i debugunit.py

To run a test interactively, create a `TestCase` instance, giving it the test name as a parameter.  To run it, call the resulting object.

```
>>> print MyTest('test1')()
before
None
```

The "2+2!=5" exception is consumed by the unittest machinery.  To get the set to run (with `setUp` and `tearDown`, etc), run the `debug()` method:

```
>>> MyTest('test1').debug()
before
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 400, in debug
    getattr(self, self._testMethodName)()
  File "debugunit.py", line 6, in test1
    self.assertEquals(2+2, 5)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 515, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 508, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: 4 != 5
```

Comment: For sure, I've been using `pdb`. I was just curious if `TestCase.Debug()` offered something better. Can you explain how to fire up the test manually?

Comment: @ben I replaced the answer with how to use `debug()` -- hope this helps!